# LXC container cannot reach other LXC container on same host

Tags: iptables, proxmox

I have following setup: Proxmox host with two LXC containers.
LXC A: 10.0.0.10
LXC B: 10.0.0.30

From within the host i can do

```
wget 10.0.0.30
```

This works perfectly.
But this does not work from within LXC A. I always get a timeout.
I can do a ping from LXC A.

This is how my vmbr0 config looks like:

```
auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1/24
        bridge-ports none
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        post-up echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o ens18 -j MASQUERADE
#       post-up   iptables -t raw -I PREROUTING -i fwbr+ -j CT --zone 1
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens18 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.10:80
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens18 -p tcp --dport 85 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.10:81
        post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens18 -p tcp --dport 443 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.10:443
#        post-up   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens18 -p tcp --dport 10000 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.10:>
        post-down iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -s '10.0.0.0/24' -o ens18 -j MASQUERADE
```

Where can i start to debug the issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer. Indeed it was that simple.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i ens18 -p tcp --dport 80 ! -s 10.0.0.0/24 -j DNAT --to 10.0.0.10:80
```

I had to add:

```
! -s 10.0.0.0/24
```

Before, this rule was applied to all traffic that originated from the interface ens18. All traffic from ens18 on port 80 was forwarded to 10.0.0.10. Since the vmbr0 is also connected to the interface ens18, this rule was always applied.

With the exclusion of traffic within the ip range 10.0.0.0/24, direct connections are now possible!